# How do I call a function with pymongo using webpy?

Tags: pymongo, web.py

I am trying to learn webpy so I can call some python programs written using pymongo from a browser window running Javascript. I am pretty new to web programming in general. Right now I am trying to start by simply adapting the sample tutorial files found here: http://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/python-and-ajax-for-beginners-with-webpy-and-jquery/

I already successfully ran the sample files in my browser window. Then I adjusted app.py to look like this:

```
import web
import datetime
import time
from collections import OrderedDict
from math import *
import sys
import operator
import pymongo

def make_text(string):
    return string

urls = ('/', 'tutorial')
render = web.template.render('templates/')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

my_form = web.form.Form(
                web.form.Textbox('', class_='textfield', id='textfield'),
                )

def check_users(user_ids):
    """ helper function for user_id-based queries """

    connection = MongoClient()
    db = connection.test

    if user_ids == "all":
        user_list = []
        for user_id in db.user_ids.find():
            user_list.append(user_id["user_id"])
        user_ids = user_list
    return user_ids

class tutorial:
    def GET(self):
        form = my_form()
        return render.tutorial(form, "Your text goes here.")

    def POST(self):
        form = my_form()
        form.validates()
        s = form.value['textfield']
        users = check_users(s)
        return make_text(users)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run it, I get "Name Error: MongoClient is not defined."

How do I get webpy to open a Mongo connection so I can run queries from a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import any module/class you intend to use. In this case replace

```
import pymongo
```

with

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

Alternatively, because you are already importing the `pymongo` module, you could simply just do

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
```